# Check constraint regarding a database relation

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database homework assignment and am having trouble with a couple parts. My DB schema is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `Movies` (
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL (CHECK year > 1928),
  `length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL (CHECK Length > 30 and Length < 280),
  `genre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL (CHECK genre = “Drama” or genre = “comedy” or genre = “sciFi” or genre =”romance” or genre = “vampire”,
  `academy_award` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studioName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `directorName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`,`year`),
  KEY `studioName` (`studioName`),
  KEY `directorName` (`directorName`),
  CONSTRAINT `Movies_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`directorName`) REFERENCES `Director` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `Movies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`studioName`) REFERENCES `Studio` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) 

CREATE TABLE `StarsIn` (
  `movieTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `movieYear` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `starName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movieTitle`,`movieYear`,`starName`),
  KEY `starName` (`starName`),
  CONSTRAINT `StarsIn_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`starName`) REFERENCES `MovieStar` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `StarsIn_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movieTitle`) REFERENCES `Movies` (`title`)
  CONSTRAINT `StarsIn_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`movieYear`) REFERENCES `Movies` (`year),

) 

CREATE TABLE `Director` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `MovieStar` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Studio` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `address` (`address`)
)
```

I have to add a couple more constraints:

1. A star may not appear in a movie made before they were born
2. A studio name that appears in Studio must also appear in at least one Movies tuple

I'm not really sure how to accomplish this after going over the MySQL constraints documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints (though it will lie to your face and claim that it created them)

Comment: Any pointers for how I would accomplish this if theoretically, mySQL did support them?

Comment: (I had mistaken your question). You should use a `before` **trigger** that checks for the constraint the usual way and aborts the transaction if it is the case. Unfortunately, AFAIK MySQL allows only one `before` trigger per table, so you will have to perform all checks there.